# Building a webview wrapper app with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, browser, webview, cross-platform

I wonder which is the best approach for building a webview wrapper application.
The app will load the website and nothing more. which browser engine uses Xamarin? Is it good to run a CMS website that contains chat, profile page, and many other complex features.

Any tips?

ps: I will use my own website not someone elses.

Comment: In terms of iOS, do not submit to Apple App Store ***just*** an app that displays a mobile website, it will be rejected, It needs to provide more features, a different UX experience, etc.. then if you opened your website in a mobile browser. Refer to the "App Store Review Guidelines", section 4(.2) specifically regarding this.

Comment: thanks, that is  a nice hint.